# XRandR crops displayed area on certain multi-monitor configurations

Tags: xorg, x11, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have total of four monitors. One (1680x1050) is connected to integrated Intel display adapter, and three (1440x900 and two 1920x1080) are connected to dedicated ATI display adapter. With certain XRandR configurations some monitors have their display area cropped, so that for example lower part of the screen is not usable.

I'd like to use configuration like this one:

```
xrandr \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x1080 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x30 --rotate normal \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1080 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --rotate normal
```

But the lower part (below the bottom edge of the bottom right screen) of the bottom left screen is cut off:

[image: Failure]

On the other hand, this configuration works:

```
xrandr \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x1050 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1080 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --rotate normal
```

, as shown here:

[image: Success 1]

Also this configuration works:

```
xrandr \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x0 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x1440 --rotate normal \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1440 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x360 --rotate normal
```

, as shown here:

[image: Success 2]

In addition, the configuration below works

```
xrandr \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x1080 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x30 --rotate normal \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1440 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --rotate normal
```

as shown here:

[image: Success 3]

**UPDATE:**

Strangely, I managed to get the wanted layout by command sequence:

```
xrandr \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x1080 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x30 --rotate normal \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1440 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --rotate normal

xrandr \
    --output HDMI2 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x30 --rotate normal \
    --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --rotate normal \
    --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 780x1080 --rotate left \
    --output HDMI-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x1080 --rotate normal \
        --primary
```

so that it works on freshly started Xorg instance, but I don't have a clue why it works. Besides, that solution seems a bit ugly. Can anybody enlighten me on this issue, please?

My OS is Arch Linux, window manager is i3, and the version of XRandR is 1.4.2. Xorg configuration files have only InputClass and Files sections.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can totally enlighten you on this one and others:

Your X11 screen (one big rectangle) is/was too small. Normally `xrandr` resizes it automatically too contain all monitors, but seems to hit a bug on your system.

The graphical representation of your setup in your screenshot reveals this problem as well (rectangle behind VGA-1 cut off). Monitors showing areas outside of the X11 screen show garbage (or nothing) in these areas.

Resize it manually with the `--fb` switch. Your total width seem to be HDMI2 + DVI-0 which are 3600 wide and the total height is stretched to the maximum by DVI-0 and rotated VGA-1, i.e. 1080 + 1440 = 2520.

```
xrandr --fb 3600x2520
```